# Normally (Gaussian) distributed in Python

Tags: python, normal-distribution

[image]

I don't understand how create normally distributed 50 samples (Y) with mean and standard deviation

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I'd encourage you to first search for an answer (when I tried that, the first hit on Google was spot on).  If, having done that, you still have questions, please do feel free to ask them here.

Comment: Also please avoid inserting pictures in posts when you could insert text! Links go dead, and formatting is lost.

Comment: @NPE Interestingly enough, didn't find a straightforward answer from SO via Google search - but there _were_ longer articles. As SO has numerous famous questions answering whatever's already in documentation, this question seems appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [Numpy](https://numpy.org/) and [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/):

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mu = 0     # mean; can be any
sigma = 1  # standard deviation; can be any
N = 50     # sample size; can be any
Y = sigma * np.random.randn(N) + mu  # generate N samples with mean 'mu' & std. dev 'sigma'

plt.hist(Y, bins=len(Y))  # plot a histogram of Y with # of bins = # of elems in Y
```

[image]

---

You can verify the standard deviation and mean of `Y` via:

```py
print(np.mean(Y)) # result: -0.245 -- will be closer to 0 with larger N
print(np.std(Y))  # result: 0.983  -- will be closer to 1 with larger N
```

---

**How it works**: `np.random` accesses the `random` library of Numpy (`np`), which contains the function `randn`; the `n` in `randn` stands for "normal", and the function draws from a normal distribution with `mu=0` and `sigma=1`. You adjust both by adding & multiplying as above, per probability theory.

Answer (score 0):

Did you even searched a bit ?

2 min google search:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html

> Draw random samples from a normal (Gaussian) distribution.
>
> The probability density function of the normal distribution, first derived by De Moivre and 200 years later by both Gauss and Laplace independently [2], is often called the bell curve because of its characteristic shape (see the example below).
>
> The normal distributions occurs often in nature. For example, it describes the commonly occurring distribution of samples influenced by a large number of tiny, random disturbances, each with its own unique distribution [2].

Quoting the provided example:

> Draw samples from the distribution:

```
>>> mu, sigma = 0, 0.1 # mean and standard deviation
>>> s = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000)
```

> Verify the mean and the variance:

```
>>> abs(mu - np.mean(s)) < 0.01
True

>>> abs(sigma - np.std(s, ddof=1)) < 0.01
True
```

> Display the histogram of the samples, along with the probability density function:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(s, 30, density=True)
>>> plt.plot(bins, 1/(sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) *
...                np.exp( - (bins - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2) ),
...          linewidth=2, color='r')
>>> plt.show()
```

See link for the plot figure.

Anyways, this homeworks and I should not have answered.